# How to know whether a unix command execution is successful

Tags: linux, shell, unix, vcftools, bcftools

I recently tried a `bcftools` command (to handle variant files) in my command line.

The command that I tried is given below

```
bcftools merge --force-samples -O z -o final.vcf.gz ethn.vcf.gz
```

However, the command was working but took a long time to merge. So, I let the system on overnight to let it run.

However, while I woke up, I see that the system is shut down due to power exhaustion

How can I know whether my last command in Unix/Linux terminal is successful?

The above command shown was just an example. You can even explain me how to check that with a `simple gzip operation`.

Though I do see the `final.vcf.gz` I can't say that the command is successful because as soon as the command starts running, I see this file being generated. So, I can't rely on that

Any help please?

Comment: Check the return value of the last command with `echo $?`. By convention `0` means success and any other value is fail but check the man page for the command to be sure.

Comment: Hi @kaylum - When I type `echo $`, I only get `$`. May I know whether I am doing this right?

Comment: You missed a question mark. It's `echo $?` and not `echo $`

Comment: Wow, yes I get `0`. However, when I issue `history` command in my command screen, I am not able to see the merge command that I executed. May I know why?

Comment: You need to check with `$?` immediately after running the command. For example, you could have done `bcftools merge --force-samples -O z -o final.vcf.gz ethn.vcf.gz; echo "Completed on $(date) with exit code $?" >> ~/mylog` to show the date and status of the command. If the system has rebooted, this information has been lost. If you run `echo $` followed by `echo $?`, the only thing you've checked is whether the `$` was successfully written to screen. Losing history is a separate question.

Comment: Sure, you can write as an answer

Comment: @TheGreat : If you fear that you forget to print the status code immediately after, you could make the habit to always write it in the same line, i.e. `yourcommand x y z; echo $?`, or `yourcommand x y z || echo FAILED $?`. BTW, do you **have** to use POSIX shell as your shell? If you can use bash or zsh, you can have the exit code of the most recent command displayed as part of your prompt. Of course all these strategies help only **if** the command really signals failure via the exit code. Unfortunately this is not always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a one-liner you can also try writing to a file, like:

```
bcftools merge --force-samples -O z -o final.vcf.gz ethn.vcf.gz && date > done.txt
```